# how many read capacity unit I need for dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

my application will query dynamodb 500queries/second, and for each query the estimated response data will be 300bytes. and my application will keep this frequency every second meaning it will continuous make 500queries/second. what's the right number I should pick for read capacity unit in my case? Thanks

Comment: You might want to start by using on-demand capacity, then study the Amazon CloudWatch metrics to see what capacity is actually being used. You could then configure a specific number of capacity units. (Or, if the usage is variable, then on-demand might work out lower cost.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/)...

> Read capacity unit (RCU): Each API call to read data from your table is a read request. Read requests can be strongly consistent, eventually consistent, or transactional. For items up to 4 KB in size, **one RCU can perform one strongly consistent read request per second.** Items larger than 4 KB require additional RCUs. For items up to 4 KB in size, **one RCU can perform two eventually consistent read requests per second.**

So if eventually consistent is good enough, then 250 RCU is all that is needed.

If you need strongly consistent, then you'd need 500 RCU.